# Visual query support for ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

I am looking for solution that will help me do visual queries on ArangoDB. Things I am looking for is something like `get me all people who have used car XYZ in past 1 month`. In this simple example I would have 2 entities `person` and `car` and one link `used_car`. Person objects would be anonymous - meaning I do not know their IDs, but I know ID of a car I am looking for.

This is just small example, I would like to be able to do more complex queries using some visual library. Visualization part is not important, important for me is if there is any guide/best practice for transformation of some visual requests to AQL code?

Although not for ArangoDB graph database, I have found something like this for Neo4j http://popotojs.com that does mostly what I want. Is there anything similar for arango?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is nothing built special purpose for ArangoDB like popotojs. However, there are a number of libraries that could allows you to build something like popotojs in a relatively short time.

Two libraries that come to mind from the top of my head are:

[KeyLines](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/) (Commercial - tutorial to use with ArangoDB [here](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/arangodb/))

[Cytoscapejs](https://js.cytoscape.org) (Open source - tutorial to use with ArangoDB [here](https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-graph-to-cytoscape/))

Note that the Cytoscape tutorial shows exporting the data and then importing into the desktop version of cityscape, I have successfully just loaded directly data from ArangoDB to Cytoscapejs via a small node app in the past.

An additional plus, is that you can use these libraries with any data and not be limited to just Neo4j.